# Requests.get in Python using "User-Agent" not simulating a browser request

Tags: python, python-requests

I have to collect information from webpages using Python from a Linux terminal, it works wonderful but some pages (not all of them) are retrieving invalid URL's when I try to use requests.get due to they have agents detectors and they don't know how to answer my request (I'm not a browser or mobile application from a Linux terminal).

Using "User-Agent" header didn't work either, I tried several different ways to send it to emulate I am a Mozilla browser:

```
user_agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
```

or

```
user_agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; hu-HU; rv:1.7.8) Gecko/20050511 Firefox/1.0.4'}
```

or many other combinations.

In some servers when I try to use this line:

```
page = requests.get(url, headers=user_agent)
```

I get a bad request, because these servers try to send me a webpage for desktop or mobile browsers and they fail to identify it.

Am I doing something wrong sending a User-Agent in this way? I tried my code in a Python Notebook and it works perfectly due to I'm currently (of course) sending a request from a browser.

Comment: Maybe they're trying to run some JavaScript to detect the browser. Have a look at the page source.

Comment: @MaximilianoRios It is unlikely, that your Python Notebook would affect headers of your `requests` requests. A tip: Try to add also some Referer header (today I found a page in India, which was replying 404 in case of missing Referer).

Comment: But it's very easy to identify the issue, I send a request from my terminal and it gets a non determined source, I send it from python notebook and it works. I will try to add a referrer to see if this works

Comment: You can always use `http://httpbin.org/get` to have headers echoed back; most likely you need more than just a User-Agent header, `requests` is *not* mangling those. Add a `Referrer`, perhaps?

Comment: @MaximilianoRios, can you give us an URL for one or some of the pages there are toubeling you?

Comment: I suggest you use a tool like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) to precisely see what is the dialog between the server and an actual browser. You will see if it involves cookies, javascript, custom headers or ...

Comment: What errors do you get exactly? How do you know that it's related to a browser detection and not to something else?

Comment: If by "bad request" you mean code 405, it means that you send GET to URL's that support POST only.

Comment: I don't have connection to the server right now but I will try to give you more details. Both websites with problems are newspapers.

Comment: In both cases it seems to be the same issue, when I write an URL in the browser I see server transforming this url into something similar adding ?desktop to the end. In case it's a mobile edition it turns into mobile.address.com/url-mobile. When I interact from a Python shell from the server the answer is www.newspaper.com/original-address%40 or something similar with a weird character at the end. I realize it cannot detect the browser or there's something tricky in there. I cannot try anything else now but I will test wireshark to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks everyone, the problem was super tricky but your recommendations helped me a lot. When I analyzed with httpbin I realized the Python Notebook and linux console were sending exactly the same request. The difference was subtle, a single space at the end of the url when they were read from the database. This single space created some sort of issue in a couple of servers and it couldn't resolve my URL properly.

Comment: User-Agent DOES work perfectly. I tested different user-agent strings and they work always, it detects mobile or desktop browsers always. My problem was totally different.

Answer (score 12):

You are using a very old user agent and indeed some sites will block you because of this.

```
>>> import requests
>>> header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0',}
>>> url = 'http://www.w3.org/'
>>> r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
>>> r.headers
CaseInsensitiveDict({'content-length': '40737', 'content-location': 'Home.html', 'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'expires': 'Tue, 24 Jun 2014 04:44:36 GMT', 'vary': 'negotiate,accept', 'server': 'Apache/2', 'tcn': 'choice', 'last-modified': 'Mon, 23 Jun 2014 11:15:15 GMT', 'etag': '"9f21-4fc7ef51956c0;89-3f26bd17a2f00"', 'cache-control': 'max-age=600', 'date': 'Tue, 24 Jun 2014 04:34:36 GMT', 'p3p': 'policyref="http://www.w3.org/2001/05/P3P/p3p.xml"', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'})
>>> r.request.headers
CaseInsensitiveDict({'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, compress', 'Accept': '*/*', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0'})
>>>
```

Answer (score 7):

I used [fake UserAgent](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-useragent)

How to use:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import requests


ua = UserAgent()
print(ua.chrome)
header = {'User-Agent':str(ua.chrome)}
print(header)
url = "https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/recent-submissions?filter=file&sort=^timestamp"
htmlContent = requests.get(url, headers=header)
print(htmlContent)
```

outPut:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1309.0 Safari/537.17
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; OpenBSD i386) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36'}
<Response [200]>
```